# Mail issues only with Google App domains

Tags: email-server, spam, spf, dkim, dmarc

I have a local mail server set up. It is connected via a dedicated IP (with an appropriate PTR record).  I have DKIM, DMARC,  and SPF set up. 
My domain has been added to Google's Postmaster Tools and is verified. 
If I use `mxtoolbox` to verify my DMARC, SPF and DKIM entries and all are valid and correct. I also verified that I am not on any blacklists.

When I send mails to mail providers like outlook.com or even gmail.com the mails reach the recipient.

Only when mails are intended for a recipient which apparently uses Google Apps do I get errors like the following:

```
< [helpme@backblaze.com](mailto:helpme@backblaze.com) >: host  [aspmx.l.google.com](http://aspmx.l.google.com/) [64.233.166.26] said: 550-5.7.1
   [24.134.224.xxx      12] Our system has detected that this message is
   550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to
   Gmail, 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.1
    [https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedMessageError](https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedMessageError)  550 5.7.1  for
   more information. c12si12050068wrv.160 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command)
```

If I google the error message (550 5.7.1) I get a slue of possibilities. The only one that possibly apply are that my IP is not authorized to send email directly.

```
550, "5.7.1", The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at your service provider instead. For more information, review  [this article.](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10336)
```

Does anyone know of a way to get the IP whitelisted or do circumvent this issue? I would prefer not to have to relay mails over a web-hosting server.

Thanks

Comment: If you follow the link, it will tell you that your reputation is bad or your emails contain "spammy" content. I, of course, can't judge any of that.
You yourself seem to be thinking about authorization and relay. How is your mail server set up? Do you use an MX record to send out emails? Or have you configured a smarthost?
In my opinion you can safely rule out SPF, DKIM and DMARC. Your bounce message would have looked different..

Comment: I only have one MX record which points to mailroute, which I use to filter spam. The email itself was a reply to asupport request to backblaze, should be fairly standard looking when it comes to mails. Would it help to add my mailserver directly as a second MX entry?

Comment: I meant for outbound email. You can either use MX lookups to determine a next hop for email delivery, or configure a smart host for relay of your outbound emails. Inbound MX record for your domain is not relevant in this case.

Comment: Have you checked Google's Postmaster site to lookup your domain's reputation? Being verified and not being blocked are two separate things. The site offers a lot of info in several dashboards.

Comment: @Rein I am sending directly, not using a smarthost. As for the postmaster dashboard ever since I have been verified, no mater which dashboard I look at, I always get the same message: "No data to display at this time. Please come back later. Postmaster Tools requires that your domain satisfies certain conditions before data is visible for this chart. " It links me to a question, that basically states that my mail volume is probably too low. Which is true - I send one mail a week to google accounts.

Comment: Right. Not much helpful then. One more thing to check, you might be on a PBL, which means certain services will not accept emails from your server. The PBL is curated list of dynamically assigned IP addresses by known ISPs, in your case I believe is Vodafone in Germany. Talos lists the IP of 24.134.224.1 as bad email reputation and shows it is listed. Your actual IP address may show similar. 
Basically it means you should send via a smarthost at your ISP or something like Google or SendGrid, or your ISP can remove your IP from the PBL.

Comment: I tried that too and got the following error message from Spamhaus: "Failed
The IP address removal process failed for the following reason:
That IP address is already removed from the PBL"

Comment: Just a quick update: I checked my specific ending-ip with Talos and there my reputation is: "EMAIL REPUTATION: Neutral, WEB REPUTATION: Neutral"